# Syntax Error When Using If, Elif, and Else Statements Within Another If Statement

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I have been working on a section of code that requires a number of variables to not equal 0, otherwise the code must be run differently. When I tried the below format, it returned elif y3 != 0: with ^^^^ pointed at the elif with the note, "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

```
    if x2*x1 != 0:
       if y2 != 0 and z2 != 0:
         #Code
       elif y2 != 0:
         #Code
       elif z2 != 0:
         #Code
       else:
         #Code
   elif x3*x2 != 0:
       if y3 != 0 and z3 != 0:
         #Code
       elif y3 != 0:
         #Code
       elif z3 != 0:
         #Code
       else:
         #Code
   elif x4*x3 != 0:
       if y4 != 0 and z4 != 0:
         #Code
       elif y4 != 0:
         #Code
       elif z4 != 0:
         #Code
       else:
         #Code
   elif x5*x4 != 0:
       if y5 != 0 and z5 != 0:
         #Code
       elif y5 != 0:
         #Code
       elif z4 != 0:
         #Code
       else:
         #Code
   else:
       #Code
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this code? If need be, I can use the "and" operator, but this format is not only shorter, but also easier to understand. Thank you for your time.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: at this moment your code has wrong indentation and this can make problem. `elif` has start in the same column as `if`

Comment: You need actual code in each block, not a comment like `# Code`.  If you had real code in there originally, the syntax error was probably actually in that code, not the `elif` line before it (syntax errors will sometimes report the line before or after the one that actually triggered the error).

Comment: The error occurred during the definition of a function so the error message did not start with "Traceback". Please explain what the indentation mistake is.

Comment: Is elif supposed to have one more indent than if?

Comment: I found the error. As Samwise suggested, the previous line of code was the problem — there was an unmatched parenthesis. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
       if y3 != 0 and z3 != 0:
           # code1
       elif y3 != 0:
           # code2
```

and you seem to be reporting that the 2nd `y3` test fails with syntax error.

Here is at least one possible explanation for observing such symptoms.

Suppose that code1 should be:

```
       if y3 != 0 and z3 != 0:
           z7 = f(g(y3))
```

but instead we wrote the assignment like this

```
           z7 = f(g(y3
```

with missing close parentheses.

Then a syntax error would be flagged, and it might be reported
on a subsequent line, as the parser is valiantly looking
for close parentheses and not finding them,
and then eventually gives up.

---

The object lesson here is to avoid long complex if / elif / elif
clauses, as they can produce unfortunate maintenance burdens.
Several abstraction techniques are available,
including table lookups.

---

As written, the original question does not supply
sufficient detail to adequately answer it.

Comment: You were right, I had forgotten to close a parenthesis in the previous line. Thanks!